# How to make Add X/Y Fields plugin work

Tags: qgis, coordinates

The QGIS 3.30 processing plugin "Add X/Y Fields" indeed adds those fields to my newly Created shapefile but that's all. Adding a new point feature does not put coordinate values in either X or Y. How do I make them operational?

Answer (score 1):

I found my own answer -- for my point features shapefile, in the Attributes Form clicking the x field then setting the Default value to $x and checking "Apply default value on update" worked. The X/Y plugin is useful to ensure the values are Decimal (double), Real, length 20, precision 10.